# Can't install phpmyadmin on ubuntu 14.04+apache2

Tags: apache2, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin via `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` but here what gives me `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`:

[image]

php5, phpmyadmin etc. modules are activated for apache. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the `cgi`  module enabled?

Comment: I guess so. If i can open hotspot.cgi from cgi-bin dir.

Answer (score 0):

When I have had the similar issues with Phpmyadmin, I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04) awesome guide and fixed everything.

Follow each step there, you might have missed something.

Comment: Well i've not activated the mcrypt module for php5. But now sudo php5enmod mcrypt command gives me nothing. And phpmyadmin page still gives me php code as text.

Comment: Show us the output of files `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and `/var/log/apache2/access.log` while you're accessing the phpmyadmin page.

Comment: error.log says:
`[Tue Apr 14 10:55:37.299791 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1651] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Apr 14 10:55:37.314711 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1651] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`

access.log:
`127.0.0.1 - - [14/Apr/2015:10:57:30 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 499 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0"`